# Need SQL query to include when NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query works perfectly and creates my temporary table with all the necessary columns, but I also want it to include rows when column 3 is `NULL` (currently it only gives me rows when column 3 has data in it).

```
  SELECT column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,column4
        ,column5
  FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2
  ON table1.column3 = table2.column3
```

I have tried different statements such as AND, OR, which did not work. It is possible that I simply did not apply the statement correctly as I am a beginner. Whenever I try something it either gives me 0 rows or hundreds of thousands more than it should.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LEFT` JOIN to return all rows from `Table1`, even when there isn't a match in `Table2`:

```
SELECT column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
    ,column5
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON table1.column3 = table2.column3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer so short that it maybe should be a comment, but.....change your `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `LEFT JOIN` rather than your `INNER JOIN`:

```
  SELECT column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,column4
        ,column5
  FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON table1.column3 = table2.column3
```